# Truncating Tables when seeding in Laravel 7 with Laratrust

Tags: php, laravel-7, laratrust

working with Laravel 7 and authenticating system Laratrust 6 and have tried seeding the tables. it has executed with some data tables with data but 3 tables did not seed. `users,role_user,permission_user` and in my terminal displayed following message  `Truncating User, Role and Permission tables`. how could I fix this problem?
my DatabaseSeeder.php file is like this

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
   public function run()
    {
        
        $this->call(LaratrustSeeder::class); 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the tables from truncating by editing your laratust_seeder.php file which is the config folder. Under the 'truncate_tables' section, set the value to false.